# Error message: Error #3115: SQL Error. Flash Sql Database table error

Tags: sql, flash, air

I try to fetch some data from db with Adobe Flash/Air.
and it throws error saying:

> "Error message: Error #3115: SQL Error. No such table 'favori' "

My code is:

```
    import flash.data.SQLConnection; 
import flash.events.SQLErrorEvent; 
import flash.events.SQLEvent; 
import flash.filesystem.File; 
import flash.data.SQLResult; 
import flash.data.SQLStatement; 
import flash.errors.SQLError; 

var conn:SQLConnection = new SQLConnection(); 

conn.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openHandler); 
conn.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler); 

// The database file is in the application storage directory 
var folder:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory; 
var dbFile:File = folder.resolvePath("debe2.db"); 

conn.openAsync(dbFile); 

function openHandler(event:SQLEvent):void 
{ 
    trace("the database was created successfully"); 
} 

function errorHandler(event:SQLErrorEvent):void 
{ 
    trace("Error message:", event.error.message); 
    trace("Details:", event.error.details); 
} 

var selectStmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement(); 

// A SQLConnection named "conn" has been created previously 
selectStmt.sqlConnection = conn; 
conn.openAsync(dbFile);

selectStmt.text = "SELECT id, name FROM favori"; 

selectStmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, resultHandler); 
selectStmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler2); 

selectStmt.execute(); 

function resultHandler(event:SQLEvent):void 
{ 
    var result:SQLResult = selectStmt.getResult(); 

    var numResults:int = result.data.length; 
    for (var i:int = 0; i < numResults; i++) 
    { 
        var row:Object = result.data[i]; 
        var output:String = "id: " + row.itemId; 
        output += "; name: " + row.itemName; 
        trace(output); 
    } 
} 

function errorHandler2(event:SQLErrorEvent):void 
{ 
     trace("Error message:", event.error.message); 
    trace("Details:", event.error.details); 
}
```

and I Googled it, most people have same problem...
I checked my db with several programs it looks fine, and I saw my table was there.
So is there any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a path issue.

you have to find the "applicationStorageDirectory" path and the db file in it.
i changed it to "desktopDirectory" and it resolved for me...